# Problem with installing Ogre sdk?

Tags: c++, ogre

I'm new to Ogre and tried to run the first tutorial, but I have faced a problem getting the
error message

> OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): 'resources_d.cfg' file not found! in
>   ConfigFile::load at ../../OgreMain/src/OgreConfigFile.cpp (line 83)

Please help, its critical!

Another question:

Is cmake important for installing the Ogre sdk?

Comment: One of the problems I faced when trying to love ogre is their tutorials and documentation is routinely out of date.  On top of that, it is never clear *which* version of the library they expect you to be using.

Answer (score 6):

After getting ogre compiled/installed using cmake
on linux those two config files live at

```
/usr/local/share/OGRE/resources.cfg
/usr/local/share/OGRE/plugins.cfg
```

just import both into your ogre project
Once ogre is installed, your project does not need cmake
To get you going for the tutorials :

How to setup eclipse with ogre :

File -> New -> C++ Project -> EmptyProject

C/C++ Build -> Environment
    OGRE_LOC   /home/scott/src/ogre_src_v1-7-3

C/C++ Build -> Settings

```
GCC C++ Compiler -> Includes

    ${OGRE_LOC}/OgreMain/include
    /usr/local/include/OGRE
    ${OGRE_LOC}/Samples/Common/include
    /usr/include/OIS

GCC C++ Linker -> Libraries (-l)

    OgreMain
    OgreTerrain
    OIS
    CEGUIOgreRenderer
```

right click project -> Properties -> Import

```
General -> File System -> 

    ONLY import those 4 files from the tutorial project 
           (NOT dist, build, makefiles ...)

        BaseApplication.cpp
        BaseApplication.h
        TutorialApplication.cpp
        TutorialApplication.h

    also import these files :

/usr/local/share/OGRE/resources.cfg
/usr/local/share/OGRE/plugins.cfg
```

Now you are ready to compile and run !

To add an Ogre model :

First do above steps to create an ogre project, assure it compiles OK.  On execution it'll render a black screen - thats fine.  Now to add a model (an Ogre) simply edit TutorialApplication.cpp so function createScene appears as :

``

void TutorialApplication::createScene(void)
{

```
Ogre::Entity* ogreHead = mSceneMgr->createEntity("Head", "ogrehead.mesh");

Ogre::SceneNode* headNode = mSceneMgr->getRootSceneNode()->createChildSceneNode();
headNode->attachObject(ogreHead);

// Set ambient light
mSceneMgr->setAmbientLight(Ogre::ColourValue(0.5, 0.5, 0.5));

// Create a light
Ogre::Light* l = mSceneMgr->createLight("MainLight");
l->setPosition(20,80,50);
```

}

Comment: thx for replay .. could you tell me how i can load any model to ogre 1.7.3

Comment: I edited original answer above with How to load an Ogre model

Comment: @ScottStensland Thank you so much for this answer! I had previously inched along on my own solving each problem as it came up until I reached the black screen stage, and first thought that something was wrong with my graphics card. But to find that the tutorial didn't have the code to show what I was expecting (an ogre)... well you saved me a huge headache!

Answer (score 1):

CMake is critical for *building* the ogre sdk from source - I would not try to configure the installation yourself. If you are using the prebuilt sdk, cmake is probably unnecessary.

As far as your error goes, it happens to be that you are trying to load resources from the `resources.cfg`. I am unaware of your operating system, however, be sure that your resources.cfg is in the same directory as your binary. If you are using MSVC and running it through the debugger, make sure your working directory (found in Project Properties -> Debugging -> Working Directory) is set to the directory of your executable.