# Setting up OGRE with Eclipse on Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, build, installation, ogre

I've just begun to wade in the waters of OGRE to introduce myself to game programming with C++ (I had done some Unity prior).

I'm having a bit of difficulty setting up the tutorial application as specified here:

http://ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Setting+Up+An+Application+-+Eclipse+-+Linux

I have downloaded OGRE 1.7.3 as a debian/Ubuntu package (from the PPA/OGRE team) so it lives on my hard drive somewhere. I am presuming I don't need to do anything with CMake since it's already been compiled.

In the tutorial instructions it says under the heading **Project Configuration**  it asks me to provide the path to OGRE but I cannot find it. I have looked in the most usual place I know /usr/bin (under /usr/bin/OGRE) and it's not there. Where is it located?

I would greatly appreciate if someone could enlighten the final steps to getting the tutorial application visible onscreen. Thanks.

Comment: Update: I have found that /usr/include/OGRE exists and contains information.

Comment: apparently are also things in  /usr/lib/OGRE.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I might be answering my own question and it might be lame, but I did enough research to figure out what the heck is going on.

http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=47695

showed me what I had to do with libraries and what to do with them when using the SDK while

[Problem with installing Ogre sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072171/problem-with-installing-ogre-sdk)

gave me the code needed for the ogre model to appear.